# How to avoid data-id from returning same id of the table element from php loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to update a record using AJAX, but when I click the button to `edit` the row I get the same `data-id` of the first row in the `table` element.

```html
<table>
  <!-- this data inside php foreach loop displayed via ajax -->
  <tr>
    <td> <a href="<?= $row->id; ?>" id="edit_btn" data-id="<?= $row->id; ?>">edit</a></td>
    <td> <a href="<?= $row->id;?>'" id="delete_btn" data-id="<?= $row->id; ?>">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
$(function($) {
  edit();
})(jQuery);

function edit() {
  $(document).on('click', '#edit_btn', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var aid = $('#edit_btn').attr('data-id');
    // var aid = $('#edit_btn').data('id');
    alert(aid);
  });
}
```

Comment: You can get attributes value use var aid = $('#edit_btn').attr('data-id');

Comment: @vadivela the OP is already doing that. It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you set some prefix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can't have multiple elements with same ID. jQuery will always use the first one found.
2. You can set a class to all your edit/delete buttons and use it to register the click event.
3. You can use `$(this)` inside the callback to manipulate only the clicked element

   ```
   <td><a class="edit_btn" data-id="<?= $row->id; ?>">edit</a></td>
   <td><a class="delete_btn" data-id="<?= $row->id; ?>">delete</a></td>

   $(document).on('click','.edit_btn', function(e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       var aid = $(this).data('id');
       alert(aid);
   });
   ```

Comment: Thank you, But I tested it and it return undefined on alert

Comment: Just saw that you used an arrow function to the click callback, that being the reason for the undefined :)

Comment: when I hover to other td links it shows different php id, but when i click it shows same id to other rows. When I use $(this) it return undefined

Comment: Thank you very much, I changed the arrow to function and it works fine now. Thank you Matei Mihai

Answer (score 2):

The main issue in your code is because you're giving all the elements in your loop the same `id`, which is invalid. `id` attributes must be unique within the DOM. You should use a class instead to attach the event handlers, then use the `this` keyword within the event handler to get a reference to the element which raised the event. The latter point means that you need to remove the arrow function and use an anonymous one instead.

That being said, there's other issues in your code which need addressing. Firstly the document.ready event handler is not an IIFE. Remove `(jQuery)` from the end of it. In addition, use `data()` to retrieve data attributes, not `attr()`. Lastly, don't use `alert()` for debugging as it coerces data types. Use `console.log()` instead.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  edit();
});

function edit() {
  $(document).on('click', '.edit_btn', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    var aid = $(e.target).data('id');
    console.log(aid);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <!-- inside your loop ... -->
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#1" class="edit_btn" data-id="1">edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="#1" class="delete_btn" data-id="1">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#2" class="edit_btn" data-id="2">edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="#2" class="delete_btn" data-id="2">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="#3" class="edit_btn" data-id="3">edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="#3" class="delete_btn" data-id="3">delete</a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you'd prefer to use the arrow function then instead of `this` you would need to use `e.target`:

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_btn', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  var aid = $(e.target).data('id');
  console.log(aid);
});
```

Comment: Thank you, It return undefined on alert, I changed arrow function to function and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should retrieve the data-id using the [data method](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

```
var aid = $('#edit_btn').data('id');
```

**Warning**

[ID's Must Be Unique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme), specifically because it will cause problems in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/id) and CSS when you try to interact with those elements.

Comment: I tested it but, it still returning the same php id of the first td element, but its deferent when iI hover to the links

Comment: That is because you didn't heed the warning about duplicate ID's in your page.